# Symfony2 nginx issue - all pages 404 not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, nginx

I've got problem with my project in symfony2 when i'm trying to run this on nginx.

www.domain/ works fine

www.domain/app_dev.php ，"An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found).Do you want to open the profiler?"

www.domain/app.php/someurl/ - 404 not found

Is it server configuration issue or should I change my .htaccess in some way to make it possible to run with nginx?

Comment: Be aware, that nginx doesn't parse .htaccess files. Those are apache specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can check my dev config (with PHP-FPM):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.example.com;

    root /var/www/web;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    index app.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /app.php/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        # try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_index app.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size   1280k;
        fastcgi_buffers   4 2560k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size   2560k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```